# Typing the tilde ~ character in DOS

Tags: special-characters, dos, tilde

In my DOS prompt I have to put in a tilde (`~`) character to open any files.

For some reason it won't show up in the DOS box/prompt.

Is there any form of Ctrl shortcut key thing that could get me to typing a `~` character?

It's only the DOS prompt that won't recognize that key is what gets me the most though.

Comment: It's possible the font you're using doesn't display that character, though the defaults shouldn't have that problem.

Answer (score 4):

Hold down the Alt key and type 0126 (zero one two six) on the numeric keypad. That is the ascii value of that character.

GWBasic:

```
10 a$="~"
20 ? asc(a$)
run
126
```

In DOS you need to begin with a 0 + value you need for other symbols and it only works on the numeric keypad.

Comment: I guess whatever's stopping the key from working is also stopping Alt-0126 from working.  Sorry, I don't have any more suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

On Spanish keyboards you can press "**Alt Gr**" and "**4**".

That key combination will write a *tilde* anywhere, including the command line.

Comment: Obviously if your keyboard is not Spanish, you can easily change the layout to Spanish within seconds in the control panel.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying to copy/paste it?

1. Start->Run->charmap
2. select the ~ char and hit select then copy
3. open the prompt window and go Alt+Space then Edit->Paste

Answer (score 1):

I typed SHIFT and the "key left to the digit 1" to produce a tilde ~ in my multimixed system.

(This actually worked. Actual keyboard is de-sg, but the multiemulated environment behaves like a DOS or WinPE US keyboard, in a command window.)